# rotation function that reacts to wind speed

Tags: javascript, android, google-weather-api, autorotate

Need to find a function in javascript flash, or css. that will alow me to rotate an image of a windmill at several different speeds. These speeds need to change with a real world wind speed.

Comment: That's interesting. What's your question?

Comment: my question is what format could i use, and is there a way i could link the speed variables for wind speed and rotation to another application such as google weather?

Answer (score 2):

You could easily accomplish this with CSS transitions. I'll give you a few tips to get you started.

Read [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/css-fundametals-css-3-transitions/) article. And [here is a quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dTj3R/2/) for you (webkit only).

Start out by defining you animation, call it `spin`, goes from 0 to 360 deg.:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {  
  from {  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }  
  to {  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }  
}
```

Then, on the windmill image apply the animation, iteration, and timing function:

```
.windmill{
    -webkit-animation-name: spin;     
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;  
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;    
}
```

Then define your speeds (**you will need to calculate these based on the image size, and wind speed formula**):

```
.windmill.mph-0  { -webkit-animation-duration: 0s; }
.windmill.mph-10 { -webkit-animation-duration: 10s; }
.windmill.mph-20 { -webkit-animation-duration: 5s; }
```

Now you use javascript to apply the wind speed changes:

```
$('.windmill').addClass('mph-10'); // stats spinning at 10 mph
```

Comment: this seems to be what i need thank you. I still would like to know however could this be linked to another application such as google weather? I want to make a the windmill respond to the wind speed within the viewers given area. Im new to web design and coding.